# MongoDB: Remove JSON from Array in a Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to remove json from an array in a document.
My document is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2f9a15a372ef8825b18736"),
    "class_section" : [ 
        {
            "class_id" : "1",
            "section_id" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "class_id" : "2",
            "section_id" : "A"
        }
    ],
    "registered_time" : ISODate("2019-01-04T17:38:29.753Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I need this following after removing **"class_id": "2"** and **"section_id": "A"** with both the conditions

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2f9a15a372ef8825b18736"),
    "class_section" : [ 
        {
            "class_id" : "1",
            "section_id" : "A"
        }
    ],
    "registered_time" : ISODate("2019-01-04T17:38:29.753Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

How can I do this in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the document by using $pull operator

```
collection.update(
  {},
  { $pull: { "class_section": { class_id: '2' } } }
);
```

Please refer to mongo documentation of $pull operator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)